# Can I select SSL/TLS version in msmtp?

Tags: ssl, msmtp

Is SSL/TLS version used by msmtp, library dependent ? (openssl, gnutls...)

I can't found ssl/tls version select option.

msmtp manual wrote:

> tls_priorities [priorities]
>
> Set the priorities for TLS sessions. The default is set by the TLS library and can be selected by using an empty argument to this command.  See the GnuTLS documentation of the gnutls_priority_init function for a description of the priorities string.

'tls_priorities' is not right ?

I think 'tls_priorities' is dependent on GnuTLS. right ?

Answer (score 0):

case by using GnuTLS. I can use --tls-priorities. (see https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Priority-Strings.html). of course build GnuTLS with `configure --enable-ssl3-support`

e.g.

```
msmtp --tls-priorities=NORMAL:-VERS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.0
msmtp --tls-priorities=NORMAL:-VERS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.1
msmtp --tls-priorities=NORMAL:-VERS-ALL:+VERS-TLS1.2
msmtp --tls-priorities=NORMAL:-VERS-ALL:+VERS-SSL3.0
```